# Re-size things on site

Tags: html, css, resize, drag

I would like to know how can I make a box or an image or whatever i want resizeable, so users can resize an object how they want to. I would like to know also how can they move these objects around the page. Id be happy if you will tell me how to make this possible by CSS and HTML.

Thank you

Comment: if you want a shallow learning curve way, load [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) , and look at the Draggable and Resizable functions of JQuery UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you want. HTML5, CSS, and Javascript. You can change it to your liking. This code in action: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.setY(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.setY(anchorY);
            bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
            topRight.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
            topLeft.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize(width, height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 578,
          height: 400
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.darthVader,
          width: 200,
          height: 138,
          name: 'image'
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

        darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 93,
          height: 104,
          name: 'image'
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

        yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();
      }

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this is not possbile with pure css and html... you would need to use [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/), and for easier work explore it library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which enables you  to do this kind of stuff easier..

Comment: dzordz, thank you for your answer! Can you please tell me where can I get any free resource for this, so maybe I can modify it and use for my needs?

Comment: see the @Shaan Singh answer, it's pretty good, and if you wanna get little more proffessional about it, explore that jQuery plugin I've linked you and search [it's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). One of great demos you got here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example/

Comment: I agree with dzordz. The answer I gave is a quick and easy fix, but it is better in the long run to learn up some jQuery.